# How to connect two Ec2 Instance so that they can Communicate with each other

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to connect two EC2 instances with each other so that they can communicate with each other.

One will have Wordpress installed, and the 2nd will have a database configured (e.g. Mysql/Mariadb).

I found the problem in the way we can connect 2 EC2 instances with each other by using private IP.

Comment: Your diagrams are very generic and you aren't specifying what exact issue you are encountering. You probably need to research AWS VPC and Security Groups. I'm voting to close this question as **too broad** because you aren't providing enough specific details for anyone to provide a specific answer.

Answer (score 23):

To keep it very simple, For any two programs to communicate with each other over a network, you need two things

1. *IP Address*
2. *Port Number*

Consider you have two EC2 instances. Lets name them

1. *Instance1*
2. *Instance2*

On each of these instances, you must be having some programs between which you want the communication to take place. Also, these programs must be running on a *PORT* of the instance. For example, tomcat instance runs on port 8080 by default. Lets name our programs:-

1. Program1 (program running on Instance1), running on port 1000
2. Program2 (program running on Instance2), running on port 2000

Let us first talk about Program1 running on port 1000 of Instance1.

1. Log onto AWS Console
2. Click on EC2 Service
3. In the left panel, click on ***Security Groups***
4. Click on the button ***Create Security Group***
5. An overlay will open.
6. Put-in the *name* and *description* of your choosing
7. Click on the tab ***Inbound*** and click on ***Add Rule***
8. Here, you are adding which port should accept connections.
9. Set the following details:-
     -Type: Custom TCP Rule
     -Protocol: TCP
     -Port Range: 1000 *[Or any other port on which your program runs]*
     -Source: External IP from where *Program1* can be accessed. It can be "Everywhere", "My IP" or a "Custom IP"
10. Click on the tab ***Outbound*** and click on ***Add Rule***
11. Repeat Step 9, if you want outbound communication.

*Repeat these steps on Instance2 and you will be good to go.*

Comment: Actual Scenario this Now.. On IMage Ec2-Scenario

Comment: The diagram does not say, which are the two _EC2 Insances_. When you say "communicate" - it seems too abstract. Maybe if you could add more details on exactly what you want to achieve and what you want to communicate, i'll be able to help you better.

Comment: I want Any Communication Between Application server and Server Cluster..

Comment: > Repeat these steps on Instance2 and you will be good to go.
How can I repeat the steps to create a Security Group attached to the database server which is in a private subnet to all inbound with External IP etc at step 9?

Comment: > Repeat these steps on Instance2 and you will be good to go.
At 9th step, it should be like:
-Type: Custom TCP Rule
-Protocol: TCP
-Port Range: 2000 [Or any other port on which your program runs]
-Source: "the first rule you created for the instance 1 - app server"

Answer (score 0):

Well , you can launch the instances in a amazon VPC , then infront of your App server you can place a Load balancer for traffic. The VPC must have a internet gateway attached to it as well. 
To access the whole VPC , you can create a jumpbox/bastion host.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your "Ec@ Scenario" image, you can add your "application server" & "backend server" under respective load balancer & can communicate with each other using LB name/end-point url. This would ensure, even if the underling EC2 instance shutdown/re-instanced, the communication won't break.