# Can I send SNMP Traps to a different network?

Tags: snmp

I'm trying to send and receive an SNMP trap using an Ubuntu VM. Works well if I send and receive it in the same VM. But is it possible to send it to another Ubuntu VM in a different network or sending it through the internet?

Used a ton of tutorial like [this](https://blog.cadena-it.com/linux-tips-how-to/snmp-trap-receiver-with-ubuntu/) but with no luck.

Any tutorials or guides for this? Been searching for days. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Learn computer network and you will see how packets are routed over the wire. SNMP is not a protocol designed for the internet, so you cannot get it through.

Comment: @LexLi but how does PySNMP have a public SNMP responder configured at demo.snmplabs.com:161??? [source](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/current/index.html)

Comment: it has, but 1) not everyone can access it. 2) attacks to it can happen.

Comment: Thanks for this. But I do want to mimic this, using my Ubuntu VM. Just for testing.

Comment: Like I said general computer networking concepts can tell you how. It is not a programming question.

Comment: @LexLi: _"SNMP is not a protocol designed for the internet, so you cannot get it through."_ Sorry but this is complete nonsense.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit exposing an SNMP agent is different from exposing HTTP. It is much more dangerous and fragile due to the protocol design itself. Anyone can leave an abstract answer like yours, but I prefer not to.

Comment: @Markkkkk It does not "always" go through, as some ISP filters out or simply blocks such UDP traffic. The "any network boundaries" part of the answer is not true as it might seem. If you are happy with an abstract answer and have no security concerns at all, anyway enjoy it.

Comment: @LexLi: "I prefer not to" and "you cannot" are two completely different things. And, with SNMPv3, it's actually not "much more dangerous and fragile" because that protocol is literally designed to fix the problems you allude to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, of course, but you will need to open up your firewalls and/or set up port forwarding so that the packets go where they need to go when they cross any network boundaries. The specific details depend on your network layout and cannot be further explained in the abstract.

Comment: OMYGOD. I did it. Thanks dude. I was running it in an AWS EC2 Instance and I had to read about networks and inbound rules. Finally getting it to work after so many google searches. Thanks! :) [this helped for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37319892/how-to-connect-two-ec2-instance-so-that-they-can-communicate-with-each-other)